# How to see what started a thread in Xcode?

Tags: multithreading, debugging, instruments, grand-central-dispatch, nsoperation

I have been asked to debug, and improve, a complex multithreaded app, written by someone I don't have access to, that uses concurrent queues (both GCD and NSOperationQueue).  I don't have access to a plan of the multithreaded architecture, that's to say a high-level design document of what is supposed to happen when.  I need to create such a plan in order to understand how the app works and what it's doing.

When running the code and debugging, I can see in Xcode's Debug Navigator the various threads that are running.  **Is there a way of identifying where in the source-code a particular thread was spawned?  And is there a way of determining to which NSOperationQueue an NSOperation belongs?**

For example, I can see in the Debug Navigator (or by using LLDB's "thread backtrace" command) a thread's stacktrace, but the 'earliest' user code I can view is the overridden (NSOperation*) `start` method - stepping back earlier in the stack than that just shows the assembly instructions for the framework that invokes that method (e.g. `__block_global_6`, `_dispatch_call_block_and_release` and so on).

I've investigated and sought various debugging methods but without success.  The nearest I got was the idea of method swizzling, but I don't think that's going to work for, say, queued NSOperation threads.  Forgive my vagueness please: I'm aware that having looked as hard as I have, I'm probably asking the wrong question, and probably therefore haven't formed the question quite clearly in my own mind, but I'm asking the community for help!
Thanks

Comment: Another thought: is such tracing possible via Instruments?  I've had a look at the System Trace template, but again I can't see a way.

Comment: Yes, Instruments will allow you to use dtrace to build this kind of tracing.

Answer (score 3):

The best I can think of is to put breakpoints on `dispatch_async`, `-[NSOperation init]`, `-[NSOperationQueue addOperation:]` and so on. You could configure those breakpoints to log their stacktrace, possibly some other info (like the block's address for `dispatch_async`, or the address of the queue and operation for `addOperation:`), and then continue running. You could then look though the logs when you're curious where a particular block came from and see what was invoked and from where. (It would still take some detective work.)

You could also accomplish something similar with `dtrace` if the breakpoints method is too slow.

Comment: Thank you Jesse - that's helpful.  Yes, I was hoping there was a method other than piecing together breakpoint outputs.  I don't have any experience of dtrace, so I'm looking into that now.

Comment: dtrace is a bit more complex; you can probably get away with using breakpoints if you configure them to continue immediately. (Right click on them, choose "Edit Breakpoint" in Xcode.)